# Не получатся разрешить зависимость android модуля во flutter проекте

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

Вот settings.gradle флатера:

```
include ':app'
include ':videofeed-android'

def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()

def plugins = new Properties()
def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')

project(':videofeed-android').projectDir = new File(rootDir, 'videofeed-android/')

if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
    pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
}

plugins.each { name, path ->
    def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
    include ":$name"
    project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
}
```

зависимость:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(path:':videofeed-android')
}
```

Ошибка

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileMinapi23DebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:minapi23DebugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve project :videofeed-android.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :videofeed-android:
> - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.